# travis error compile unrecognized command line option "-Wno-extra-semi"

Tags: php, travis-ci

I am trying to install a php-extension of datastax cassandra driver.
I have ran this test in 5.5 and 5.6. for PHP 7 I have the following error which kills the build:

> cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-extra-semi"

the build itself inside the .travis.yml file:

```
  - sudo apt-add-repository ppa:linuxjedi/ppa -y
  - sudo apt-get update
  - sudo apt-get install -y libuv-dev libssl-dev
  - git clone https://github.com/datastax/php-driver.git
  - cd php-driver
  - git submodule update --init
  - cd ext
  - ./install.sh
```

**UPDATE**
as per recommended:

```
sed -i s/-Wno-extra-semi// ./install.sh
```

but now I get this error during the build:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/home/travis/.phpenv/versions/7.0snapshot/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20151012/cassandra.so' - /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/7.0snapshot/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20151012/cassandra.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

Also if you are wondering here is the ./install.sh file:

```
basedir=$(cd $(dirname $0); pwd)

check_executable () {
  for executable; do
    command -v $executable >/dev/null 2>&1 || {
      echo >&2 "Unable to find '$executable', make sure it is installed and is in the PATH.  Aborting."
      exit 1
    }
  done
}

check_executable cmake grep sed

set -ex

rm -Rf /tmp/php-driver-installation
mkdir /tmp/php-driver-installation
pushd /tmp/php-driver-installation

mkdir build
builddir=$(cd build; pwd)

echo "Compiling cpp-driver..."
mkdir cpp-driver
pushd cpp-driver
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-fPIC" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=$builddir -DCASS_BUILD_STATIC=ON \
  -DCASS_BUILD_SHARED=OFF -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -DCASS_USE_ZLIB=ON \
  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR:PATH=lib $basedir/../lib/cpp-driver/
make
make install
popd
rm -Rf cpp-driver
rm -f build/lib/libcassandra.{dylib,so}
mv build/lib/libcassandra_static.a build/lib/libcassandra.a

popd

echo "Compiling and installing the extension..."
phpize

echo ./configure --with-cassandra=$builddir --with-libdir=lib
LIBS="-lssl -lz -luv -lm -lstdc++" LDFLAGS="-L$builddir/lib" ./configure --with-cassandra=$builddir --with-libdir=lib
make
make install

rm -Rf /tmp/php-driver-installation
```

Comment: Somewhere (probably in `./install.sh`), you're passing `-Wno-extra-semi` to a C or C++ compiler with that warning being unknown thereto.

Comment: @набиячлэвэлиь since this is from datastax themselves, do I tell them that or is there a way to remove that even if that git is downloaded from them

Comment: `sed -i s/-Wno-extra-semi// ./install.sh`

Comment: @набиячлэвэлиь i replace that instead of ./install.sh?

Comment: You can replace all occurrences of `-Wno-extra-semi` either manually (if you have the file checked in) or by `sed`ding it out if you get it from somewhere else.

Comment: @набиячлэвэлиь please check the update

Comment: Now that's a different question altogether. You're missing `cassandra.so` (a shared library), but as to why, I do not know.

Comment: @набиячлэвэлиь - it is the same story. the ./install.sh compiles the cassandra.so file - due to the compile error it doesnt compile. As I mentioned all the way the beginning, that the purpose of this question was related to the installation of the cassandra extension as I outlined.

Comment: Same problem here, anyone found the solution?

Comment: @Michal they have started to make their driver PHP7 compatible, however im getting new errors. due to new compiling methods they have introduced. Check their new .travis.yml as they now use the container method.

Comment: @azngunit81 Today I created bug report https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/PHP-72 I hope someone is going to fix it soon